# xsl:fo template match not firing on nested list

Tags: templates, xslt, xsl-fo

I need to use a hyphen for the bullet on a nested list applying xsl:fo. I have two templates to match but only one is being applied. If I use just the first template, the outer list gets the template applied. If I use just the second template, the nested list gets the template applied. The pattern I am attempting to match in the second template is any unordered list with a list item as a parent. Any help on getting my desired output is greatly appreciated.

**XML**

```
<ThisNode>
<ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three
        <ul>
            <li>Sub-Item One</li>
            <li>Sub-Item Two</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
    <li>Item Five</li>
</ul>
</ThisNode>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="ul">
<fo:list-block>
    <xsl:for-each select="./li">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block font-weight="bold">•</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="8pt">
                <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:list-block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li//ul">
<fo:list-block start-indent="8pt">
    <xsl:for-each select="./li">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block font-weight="bold">-</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="16pt">
                <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:list-block>
</xsl:template>

<fo:block text-align="left">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./ThisNode"/>
</fo:block>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
• Item One
• Item Two
• Item Three
    - Sub-Item One
    - Sub-Item Two
• Item Four
• Item Five
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT USING EITHER JUST THE 1ST TEMPLATE OR USING BOTH**

```
• Item One
• Item Two
• Item ThreeSub-Item OneSub-Item Two
• Item Four
• Item Five
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT USING ONLY THE 2ND TEMPLATE**

```
Item One Item Two Item Three
    - Sub-Item One
    - Sub-Item Two
Item Four Item Five
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a good place for a `call-template` with a `mode`, to distinguish between the 2 cases. The outer template calls the inner template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <fo:block text-align="left">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="ThisNode"/>
      </fo:block>
   </xsl:template>


   <xsl:template match="ul">
      <fo:list-block>
         <xsl:for-each select="li">
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                  <fo:block font-weight="bold">•</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="8pt">
                  <fo:block>
                     <!-- I'm not quite sure what you want here -->
                     <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="ul" mode="inner"/>
                  </fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </fo:list-block>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ul" mode="inner">
      <fo:list-block start-indent="8pt">
         <xsl:for-each select="./li">
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                  <fo:block font-weight="bold">-</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="16pt">
                  <fo:block>
                     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </fo:list-block>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following stylesheet illustrates a possible solution. Your approach is not far off - however, it fails to account for the behaviour of XSLT processors. This expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

by default returns any text nodes that are children of the context node. But in your case (template match for `li` elements), *all* descendant text nodes are output, not only the immediate children of `li`.

Therefore, the stylesheet below uses

```
<xsl:value-of select="child::text()"/>
```

to retrieve the text content of a `li` element instead and `<xsl:apply-templates>` to process any `li` elements that are sub-items of it.

As your title states,

> xsl:fo template match not firing on nested list

You diagnosed it correctly. This is because - once inside a template match for `li` - you do not let the XSLT processor process descendant `li` elements.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/ThisNode">
      <fo:root>
         <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
                              page-height="29.7cm"
                              page-width="21cm"
                              margin-top="1cm"
                              margin-bottom="2cm"
                              margin-left="2.5cm"
                              margin-right="2.5cm">
               <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
               <fo:region-before extent="3cm"/>
               <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
         </fo:layout-master-set>

         <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
         </fo:page-sequence>
      </fo:root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ul[parent::ThisNode]">
      <fo:list-block>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:list-block>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ul[parent::li]">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="li">
      <fo:list-item>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="parent::ul/parent::ThisNode">
                <fo:list-item-label start-indent="1cm">
                   <fo:block font-weight="bold">&#x2022;</fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:list-item-body start-indent="1.5cm">
                   <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="child::text()"/></fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-body>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:list-item-label start-indent="3cm">
                   <fo:block font-weight="bold">-</fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:list-item-body start-indent="3.5cm">
                   <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-body>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>  
      </fo:list-item>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output (XSL-FO)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="1cm"
                             margin-bottom="2cm"
                             margin-left="2.5cm"
                             margin-right="2.5cm">
         <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
         <fo:region-before extent="3cm"/>
         <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:list-block>
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label start-indent="1cm">
                  <fo:block font-weight="bold">•</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="1.5cm">
                  <fo:block>Item One</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>Item One
    <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label start-indent="1cm">
                  <fo:block font-weight="bold">•</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="1.5cm">
                  <fo:block>Item Two</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>Item Two
    <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label start-indent="1cm">
                  <fo:block font-weight="bold">•</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="1.5cm">
                  <fo:block>Item Three

    </fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>Item Three

            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label start-indent="3cm">
                  <fo:block font-weight="bold">-</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="3.5cm">
                  <fo:block>Sub-Item One</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>Sub-Item One
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label start-indent="3cm">
                  <fo:block font-weight="bold">-</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="3.5cm">
                  <fo:block>Sub-Item Two</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>Sub-Item Two


    <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label start-indent="1cm">
                  <fo:block font-weight="bold">•</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="1.5cm">
                  <fo:block>Item Four</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>Item Four
    <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label start-indent="1cm">
                  <fo:block font-weight="bold">•</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="1.5cm">
                  <fo:block>Item Five</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>Item Five
</fo:list-block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**Output (PDF)**

> [image]